# Is it bad practice to use inline styles?

Tags: html, css, inline-code

Is it bad practice to occasionally put some CSS directly into some HTML tags if I am sure that it won't be used again?

For instance:

```
<div style="padding-left: 0"></div>
```

Or do I have to systematically create new class even for little tweaks that will pollute my CSS file?

Comment: The answer is "it depends".

Comment: It's worth pointing out that inline styling has higher specificity. While this works, it may not be *as* maintainable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is fine. Stylesheets are used mostly to style multiple pages in the same manner and for easier editing. Putting css directly in html also overrides all other conflicting styles.

Comment: It's also what happens when you use Javascript to style an element (using `Element.style`) - styles are inserted inline.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [**Programmers** Stack Exchange site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) that's a better fit for questions like this.

Here are two existing questions there that cover this particular topic:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/138538/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-inline-styling-with-generated-code

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/125893/when-should-i-use-a-css-class-over-inline-styling